# tic tac toe Jcreator stuck

Tags: java, jcreator

Here is how the entire thing looks like now.

And then there is the details that you're forced to add and more details and more details and more details and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tictactoe {
    static char[][] MakeMove(char[][] spelplan, char spelare, int rad, int kolumn) {
        spelplan[rad][kolumn] = spelare;
        char[][] board = new char[4][4];
        System.out.println(spelplan[rad][kolumn]);
        return spelplan;
    }

    static boolean CheckMove(char[][] spelplan, int x, int y) {
        if (spelplan[x][y] != ' ') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    static void SkrivUtSpelplan(char[][] spelplan) {
        System.out.println("-------");
        System.out.println("|" + spelplan[1][1] + "|" + spelplan[1][2] + "|" + spelplan[1][3] + "|");
        System.out.println("|-+-+-|");
        System.out.println("|" + spelplan[2][1] + "|" + spelplan[2][2] + "|" + spelplan[2][3] + "|");
        System.out.println("|-+-+-|");
        System.out.println("|" + spelplan[3][1] + "|" + spelplan[3][2] + "|" + spelplan[3][3] + "|");
        System.out.println("-------");
    }

    static boolean KollaVinst(char[][] spelplan) {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char spelplan[][] = new char[4][4];
        char spelare;
        int rad = 3, kolumn = 3, i = 0;
        for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y < 4; y++) {
                spelplan[x][y] = ' ';
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-------");
        System.out.println("| | | |");
        System.out.println("|-+-+-|");
        System.out.println("| | | |");
        System.out.println("|-+-+-|");
        System.out.println("| | | |");
        System.out.println("-------");

        while (KollaVinst(spelplan) == false) {

            CheckMove(spelplan, rad, kolumn);

            for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    spelare = 'X';
                } else {
                    spelare = 'O';
                }

                System.out.println("Spelare 1 skriv vilken rad: 1-3");
                int x = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

                System.out.println("Spelare 1 skriv vilken kolumn: 1-3");
                int y = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

                if (CheckMove(spelplan, x, y) == true) {
                    MakeMove(spelplan, spelare, x, y);
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
                SkrivUtSpelplan(spelplan);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you are stuck at? what are you trying to achieve that is not working?

Also, you could consider posting this (when you are done) on codereview.stackoverflow.com for some suggestions on how to improve this. One suggestion I can make: start all your methodnames with lowercase. Classes: uppercaseFirst , methods lowerCaseFirst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you posted so far (I am really hoping for an edit that clarifies what you are attempting)

I am assuming you are trying to build a loop that doesn't end until the board is finished.
until it is finished, a move is asked from the player. the move is made (if legal). Then the board is printed.

your code has a number of issues:

1. CheckMove(spelplan, rad, kolumn) is only ever executed with rad=3,kolumn=3. I would expect this to be run using the user input.
2. You reuse your loop variables. (int i = new scanner)  and later (for i=i). never do that. the i=i is pointless anyway and you end up doing i++ which means you lose the user input.
3. inside the while loop you never do makeMove(spelplan, i, j). I would expect this to occur before printing out the board.
4. the for loops (i and j) don't seem to be useful. Your method skrivutSpelPlan already prints the board and it only needs to be called once. you don't use the loop variables i or j.

I am fighting the urge to write out suggestions / code as you indicated you didn't want it.
In pseudocode, you would want your loop structured like:

```
while (!isBoardSolved) {
    (x,y) = getUserInput(); // this is not java :D don't use it
    if (isLegalMove(x,y)) {
         makeMove(x,y);
    } else {
         reportError();
    }
    printBoard();
}
```

in your printBoard method, you should loop. you currently have hardcoded [0] [1] etc. use a forloop for row and forloop for col.

your checkmove doesn't check the board. it checks if the board[x][y] != board[x][y] which is never true. (well ok technically in a multithreaded environment, it could be true if a racecondition occurs and it's accessible) 
You have to think what checkMove does.

MakeMove is ok, except you don't need to return the new playing field.
if you do

```
char[][] board = new char[4][4];
MakeMove(board, 'a', x, y);
System.out.println(board[x][y]); // should print 'a' unless x or y were out of bounds.
```

then board gets updated and the a is printed.

ok I'm trying not to spoil your fun, just giving pointers.
Please update the question with the details of your problem. where are you stuck, what do you need.

When you have this working I recommend posting it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and get some more feedback on good coding style and practices.

to test diagonals, you could use:

```
// y = row number, so y = y + 1 means the row below y
// x = column number. so x = x + 1 means the column to the right of x
public boolean isSolved(char[][] board) {
    // check horizontal rows
    return isHorizontalSolved(board) || isVerticalSolved(board) || isDiagonalSolved(board);
}

public boolean isHorizontalSolved(board) {
    for (int y = 0; y < board.length; ++y) { 
        // for each row, test if all columns are the same
        boolean solved = true;
        char first = board[y][0];
        for (int x = 0; x < boards[y].length; ++x) {
            if (boards[y][x] == ' ' || first != boards[y][x]) { 
                // if an element is not filled in, this row is not solved
                // if an element in this row is different than any other element, this row is not solved
                solved = false;          
            }
        }
        if (solved == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// check vertical rows
// leaving this for your own imagination

// check diagonals
public boolean isDiagonalSolved(char[][] board) {
    // check topLeft to bottomRight:
    char first = board[0][0];
    boolean solved = true;
    for (int y = 0, x = 0; y < board.length && x < board[y].length; ++y, ++x) {
        if (board[y][x] == ' ' || first != board[y][x]) {
            // if field is empty or the fields are not all equal to one another
            solved = false;
        }
    }
    if (solved) {
        return true;
    }

    int topRightX = board[0].length - 1;
    solved = true;
    first = board[0][topRightX];
    for (int y = 0, x = topRightX; y < board.length && x >= 0; ++y, --x) {
        if (board[y][x] == ' ' || first != board[y][x]) {
            // if field is empty or the fields are not all equal to one another
            solved = false;
        }
    }
    if (solved) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Can't promise it's error less but this is roughly what I would do.
for diagonal, traverse topleft to bottom right (0,0) (1,1) (2,2)   and topright to bottom left (0, 2), (1,1) (2,0)

with a gameboard of 3*3 you can hardcode this but I'm used to using loops.

Comment: Im done with almost all now but im having problems with checking the winner

Comment: Ok... I would assume to check if anyone has won or there is a tie, you go over the gameboard horizontally, vertically and diagonally and check if there are 3 moves by the same player in a row. horizontally you keep x the same, loop over y. vertically keep y the same loop over x. for diagonal, x,y = 0, x++ and y++. other diagonal:  x = 2; y = 0; x--; y++;   if board is same char 3 times, you have a winner.

Comment: An alternative to that is, you check for a winner when a specific user has made a move. (switching between a and b I assume). If the board is "won" after the current player made a move, then the current player is the winner.  to check for tie: when checking if noone won but you don't find any empty fields, it is a tie

Comment: what do you mean by loop over x and loop over y?

Comment: Oh sorry in your code you use i and j (with i < rad and j < kolumn). I'm used to using x and y (though my example code is not exactly like I would write it). with x I generally mean horizontal row index, y vertical row index.

Comment: can you give an example on the kind of loop i would use? Im kind of confused.

Comment: This seems very complicated. Is there no easier way except hardcoding?

Comment: You can try implementing it in your own way. I just wrote out how I would do it. You can probably simplify it a little.

Comment: Did you write the "for (int y = 0, x = 0; y < board.length, x < board[y].length; ++y, ++x) {" wrong?

Comment: Possibly, it was psuedocode. though on iteration 1, x=0,y=0 , iteration 2: x=1,y=1, iteration 3: x=2,y=2  ... aaah I see it. 

y < board.length && x < board[y].length    , replace the , there with &&. updated the code snippet but note: "Can't promise it's error less but this is roughly what I would do."

Comment: The isSolved stays false whatever i do. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I recommend you use a debugger and put a breakpoint on the method.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html
or
http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/

Comment: one last thing. Are these lines of code in horizontal written correctly?                                                       char first = board[y][0];
        for (int x = 0; x < boards[y].length; ++x) {
            if (boards[y][x] == ' ' || first != boards[y][x]) {

Comment: Write output to console or into a file to check.
for each y, it fetches the first element, and loops over [y][0] .. [y][2] and compares them. if any field is empty or different from [y][0] then the board is not solved.  as far as I can see this line is correct but well they are just examples of how you can do it. It's best if you write it yourself in a way you're comfortable with it. If you can't use a debugger, print a lot of lines to system.out (printf debugging) though I recommend investing some time in getting familiar with your IDE and getting it set up)